# curl lot loaded after adding SFTP support

Tags: php5, curl, php.ini

I installed Tartarus, and since my current curl didn't have SFTP
support I've done [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195545/how-to-enable-sftp-support-in-curl) .
Tartarus worked fine but I started to receive mails:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/curl.so' - /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4:
>   version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not found (required by
>   /usr/lib/php5/20100525/curl.so) in Unknown on line 0

After that I've noticed my Magento sites (admin) didn't work.
Error log shows this:

> [Thu Dec 05 23:33:57 2013] [warn] [client x.x.x.x] mod_fcgid: stderr:
>   PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_setopt() in
>   /var/www/clients/client1/web6/web/lib/Varien/Http/Adapter/Curl.php on
>   line 87

phpinfo() - there is no curl extension loaded :S

```
cat /etc/php5/cgi/conf.d/20-curl.ini shows: 

; configuration for php CURL module 
; priority=20 
extension=curl.so
```

Googled around but without luck :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after several tests I removed everything for curl:

```
rm /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4*
sudo apt-get remove curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

Then installed:

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

Warrning: you lose SFTP support.

UBUNTU 12.10 with curl 7.24.0, libcurl/7.29.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP